# how to navigate from one view to another in ios after successful login

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I need to navigate from one view to another after successful login I'm using storyboard and I'm stuck in this process I'm new to IOS so please guide me to overcome this problem

Comment: I know its a silly question but I dont know how to do that i tried segue method but its not working for me

Comment: This is not enough information. We know that you're stuck, but we don't know after which step you get confused, and "not working for me" doesn't tell exactly what is not working.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use "`[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"LoginSucceeded" sender:self]`" for my own projects, when whatever method I'm using for authentcating finally comes back as a "success".

Although you will need to replace "`@LoginSucceeded`" with the actual segue name that you give to the segue that gets you to the next screen.

And you probably also need an appropriate "Login Failed" segue / screen or "Authentication Error" state.